# Do not put the label inline in a form-inline - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a form, I have in this two fields inline because they are in a form-inline div, I want to put the label of these above the fields and not next to them. How to remove form-inline from them without affecting the fields?

[Here is a CodePen](https://codepen.io/MehdiX/pen/rNapdJv)

```html
<main id="contact_part">
    <article class="mb-5 row">
        <h1>Nous Contacter</h1>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="" method="post" id="contact_form">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <label class="" for="name_contact">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="name_contact" placeholder="Nom" required>

                    <label class="" for="lastNameContact">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="lastName_contact" placeholder="Prénom" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="email_contact">E-Mail</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email_contact" id="email_contact" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="message_contact">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message_contact" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </article>
</main>
```

```css
#contact_part article {
    background-color: #FFF989;
    font-family: main, "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    color: #565656;
    padding: 50px;
}

#contact_part .row {
    display: block;
}

#contact_part h1 {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
}

#contact_form {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#contact_form .form-inline label {

}

#contact_form input, #contact_form textarea {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
    background-color: #FFF989;
}
```

Comment: Just make your placeholders `placeholder=""` and move the label outside the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you no need to use `form-inline` `class` instead use like below code. Your form will look good.

```
<main id="contact_part">
    <div class="container">
        <article class="mb-5 row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Nous Contacter</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <form action="" method="post" id="contact_form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="custom-control pl-0" for="name_contact">First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_contact" placeholder="First Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="custom-control pl-0" for="lastNameContact">Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName_contact" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="custom-control pl-0" for="email_contact">E-Mail</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email_contact" id="email_contact" class="form-control" placeholder="example@example.com" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="custom-control pl-0" for="message_contact">Message</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message_contact" placeholder="Message" rows="5" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</main>
```

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/dyPJeNG).

Use `col-12` instead of `col-md-12` `class` for better performance. Don't use `row` without `container` or `container-fluid`. If you use only `row` it give you `horizontal` `scroll bar`. Your `code` will look like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Or**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Fluid view or 100% Browser width**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">Content</div>
        <div class="col-12">Content</div>
        <div class="col-12">Content</div>
        <div class="col-12">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
.form-inline label
{
margin-bottom:3em;
}
```

Or You can move the label outside the`<div class="form-inline">`

Comment: I don't think that is possible since there will be two online forms, each in their own line -> https://codepen.io/MehdiX/pen/rNapdJv

Comment: That's right but you used `form-inline label` instead of `.form-inline label` in your codepen

Comment: Indeed, it turns out that it works, but a little shifted to the left, but it's still a solution

Comment: Okay. Glad  I was able to contribute to the solutions

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, let me know if this works: https://codepen.io/luke-richter/pen/XWJVqWO

```js
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

```css
#contact_part{
    background-color: #FFF989;
    font-family: main, "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    color: #565656;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->


<main id="contact_part">
<div class="container ">
<div class="row">
<h2>Inline form with heading above inputs</h2>
</div>
<form action="#">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
<label for="firstname" class="control-label">Firstname1</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="lastname" class="control-label">Last Name2</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="lastname" class="control-label">Last Name3</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3">
<textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3"><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```